Why are items in RecyclerView not shown when back is pressed?
So, I have a FragmentA. It contains a RecyclerView. It shows the list of items as expected at first. Now, when user clicks on one of the item, we navigate to FragmentB (FragmentA still in backstack). When user presses back, the backstack pops and now, we're on FragmentA but, now, the RecyclerView is empty.
I'm using ViewModel, MutableStateFlow and StateFlow for all this.
Here's the code:
ViewModel:
private val _uiData = MutableStateFlow(UIData())
val uiData = _uiData.asStateFlow()
private val _uiState = Channel<UIState>()
val uiState = _uiState.receiveAsFlow()
fun onUIEvent(uiEvent: UIEvent) = when (uiEvent) {
  is UIEvent.LoadBondedDevices -> loadBondedDevices(uiEvent.bluetoothDevices)
}
private fun loadBondedDevices(bluetoothDevices: Set<BluetoothDevice?>) {
    _uiState.trySend(UIState.Loading)
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val bondedDevices = bluetoothDevices.filterNotNull()
            .map { bluetoothDevice: BluetoothDevice ->
                BondedDevice(
                    bluetoothDevice.name,
                    bluetoothDevice.address
                )
            }
        _uiData.update { uiData: UIData -> uiData.copy(bondedDevices = bondedDevices) }
        _uiState.trySend(UIState.Idle)
    }
}

FragmentA:
@AndroidEntryPoint
class FragmentA : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_a) {
    private val viewBinding by lazy {
        FragmentABinding.bind(requireView())
    }
    private val viewModel by viewModels<FragmentAViewModel>()
    private val bluetoothAdapter by lazy {
        (requireContext()
            .applicationContext
            .getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager).adapter
    }
    private val bondedDevicesAdapter by lazy {
        BondedDevicesRecyclerViewAdapter { bondedDevice: BondedDevice ->
            // An item is clicked
            // Navigate to FragmentB
            findNavController().navigate(
                FragmentADirections.actionFragmentAToFragmentB(
                    bondedDevice
                )
            )
        }
    }
    private val bluetoothStateBroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            if (intent == null) return
            val bluetoothState = intent.getIntExtra(
                BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,
                BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF,
            )
            if (bluetoothState == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF) {
                // Bluetooth is turning off
                try {
                // Navigate to FragmentC
                } catch (ignored: Exception) {}
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        // Check if Bluetooth is supported
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Bluetooth is not supported
            // Navigate to FragmentD
            return
        }
        viewBinding.recyclerView.adapter = bondedDevicesAdapter
        viewBinding.refreshEfab.setOnClickListener { loadBondedDevices() }
        // Listen for UIData changes and show them on screen
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
                viewModel.uiData.collect { uiData: UIData ->
                    if (uiData.bondedDevices.isEmpty()) {
                        viewBinding.emptyMtv.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        viewBinding.recyclerView.visibility = View.GONE
                    } else {
                        viewBinding.emptyMtv.visibility = View.GONE
                        viewBinding.recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                    bondedDevicesAdapter.submitList(uiData.bondedDevices)
                }
            }
        }
        // Listen for UIState changes and show them on screen
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
                viewModel.uiState.collect { uiState: UIState ->
                    when (uiState) {
                        UIState.Idle -> viewBinding.linearProgressIndicator.hide()
                        UIState.Loading -> viewBinding.linearProgressIndicator.show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Register receiver to monitor Bluetooth state
        requireActivity().registerReceiver(
            bluetoothStateBroadcastReceiver,
            IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)
        )
        loadBondedDevices()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        // Unregister the registered receiver
        try {
            requireActivity().unregisterReceiver(bluetoothStateBroadcastReceiver)
        } catch (ignored: Exception) {
        }
    }

    private fun loadBondedDevices() {
        // Check Android version and Bluetooth permissions
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    requireContext(),
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    requireContext(),
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                // We don't have all Bluetooth permissions
                // Navigate to FragmentE
                return
            }
        }
        // We have all Bluetooth permissions
        // Check if Bluetooth is enabled
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled) {
            // Bluetooth is disabled
            // Navigate to FragmentC
            return
        }
        // All good
        // Load list of bonded devices
        viewModel.onUIEvent(UIEvent.LoadBondedDevices(bluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices))
    }
}

RecyclerViewAdapter is ListAdapter.
class BondedDevicesRecyclerViewAdapter @Inject constructor(
    private val onClick: (BondedDevice) -> Unit,
) : ListAdapter<BondedDevice, BondedDevicesRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>(
    BondedDeviceDiffItemCallback()
) {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            ItemBondedDeviceBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false,
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int, payloads: MutableList<Any>) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(
        private val viewBinding: ItemBondedDeviceBinding,
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(viewBinding.root) {
        init {
            viewBinding.root.setOnClickListener { onClick(getItem(absoluteAdapterPosition)) }
        }

        fun bind(bondedDevice: BondedDevice) {
            viewBinding.titleMtv.text = bondedDevice.name
            viewBinding.subtitleMtv.text = bondedDevice.address
        }
    }
}

class BondedDeviceDiffItemCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<BondedDevice>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: BondedDevice, newItem: BondedDevice): Boolean {
        return oldItem.address == newItem.address
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: BondedDevice, newItem: BondedDevice): Boolean {
        return oldItem.hashCode() == newItem.hashCode()
    }
}


What are you doing with the UiState?

That's to show a progressbar while loading but, I don't think that is causing any issue

What I suspect is maybe lifecycleScope is still active and not getting re-run. Maybe you're expecting it to cancel and rerun the code inside

viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) should handle it

what I've observed is, when we popback to FragmentA, RecyclerView is empty but, now if I rotate the screen, all items are showing

That's because of lifecycle changes and your flows being triggered again.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Solved (Finally)!
After hours of searching, debugging and what not, it worked!
Here's what worked:
In FragmenA, I was using by lazy for viewBinding which was creating the problem. I changed it to lateinit var and initialized it in onCreateView like this:
FragmentA:
@AndroidEntryPoint
class FragmentA : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_a) {
    private lateinit var viewBinding: AFragmentBinding
    // Unchanged code from question
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        viewBinding = AFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater)
        return viewBinding.root
    }
    // Unchanged code from question
}

Don't know why but this is working but, not the code in question.
